# RectBivariateSpline returning nans for perfecly valid input array

Tags: python-3.x, interpolation

I have a weird problem regarding RectBivariateSpline. I want to do a 2D interpolation for two structurally identical text files (only differing in the last column), called "model_1.txt" and "model_2.txt" each with 1000x500 data points, where the upper triangle is mostly 0. If I do so for model 1, everything works fine. If I perform the interpolation for model 2 there is no error, int(x,y) gives me 0 in the surrounding were everything data wise is 0 (as it should) but nan in the regime, where the data is non-zero (even at the input points).

I've already checked, that not a single entry in the second data file is nan or any other type else that float (not even negative). When plotting the data everything appears smooth.

This is the (example) code I use for both files:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline

name = 'model_%d.txt'%(model) 
Alldata = np.loadtxt(name,delimiter=',') # has 3 columns: x,y,data
xsdata = np.unique(Alldata[:,0]) # 1000 points
ysdata = np.unique(Alldata[:,1]) # 500 points
data = np.reshape(Alldata[:,2],(len(xsdata),len(ysdata))) # (1000,500) points
int = RectBivariateSpline(xsdata,ysdata,data,kx=1,ky=1)
```

Functions like interp2d and others have the same issue. Did anybody ever had a similar problem or an idea, what else I could try to make that work, since I have no idea anymore what to to (especially because the model 1 file works fine and they are structurally identical).

Happy holidays :)

Comment: what is `model` here ?  `name = 'model_%d.txt'%(model)` ?  it is not defined...

Comment: It is just a number (1 or 2) to load the data files with three columns each and defined as an external input parameter (outside of the example piece).